Do additionally installed drivers survive Windows 11 "Reset this PC"?
I have laptop in which I swapped SSD for aftermarket one and don't have access to the recovery media/image. Some drivers needed for laptop to function properly need to be installed from vendor's website. I'd like to sell this laptop and give buyer usual Windows 11 first-boot experience.
If I do clean Windows 11 install with local or (my) Microsoft account, install drivers from the website and then "Reset this PC" will installed drivers survive?
EDIT: This is one-off thing, I know I can extract those drivers and bake them in install media but I feel doing it as I described above is less effort in my situation.

No, "Reset this PC" will delete everything, including drivers.
If the drivers are not in Windows 11 via Windows Update, then the next buyer will have to install the drivers themselves.
Does this mean you can't do anything about it? No, absolutely not, there are ways. Here's what you need to do:
Reset the PC
Reset the PC like you normally would.
After the reboot, you get the setup wizard. Do this normally as if this is your own PC. Although you probably will want to use something like User and no password.
Configure anything you want for the new owner
Run Windows updates, install drivers and remove bloat etc, that you want to be ready for the next owner. This step is basically what a manufacturer would do too before shipping it to you.
Run sysprep to trigger an OOBE
Now that the laptop is ready, we want to create the "Out of Box Experience" (or OOBE for short).
We can do this by running a Command prompt as administrator, then navigate to C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep

This will popup a small window asking you how to sysprep. Change the 2nd option from reboot to shutdown and hit OK.
The system will now shutdown.
Get the PC to the buyer
You have done everything now as if the PC is bought fresh. When the new buyer starts the PC, it will boot them into the Out of Box Experience, and they get asked for certain settings and their username and password. Once they login, all the drivers you already installed will be there.
One final note
Note that if you want to pre-install software, make sure you install the software for All Users, and not for your own user. Your user will be gone after the OOBE has been run.
Educational Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULUEzBki1yo


Good post! I have one suggestion though: instead of running "Reset PC" on the existing computer, download Windows 11 from MS and install a fresh copy. It will be more up to date and come from MS where as the existing image may come from an OEM.

Reset PC would install a more recent version than what you install through an ISO. Reset PC has nothing to do with the OEM image.

@Ramhound technically not true because Reset PC will reset the PC to an OEM image if its present in the factory partition. In this question OP told us they swapped the SSD and that the factory partition is gone, and in that case, Reset PC with delete all, will indeed use a fresh install of the current installed version of Windows. This does mean that if you have 22H1 installed, it will not automatically install a newer version. But the Windows Update Step will eventually do this, which is what Rob suggested.

@LPChip - It would be near impossible for the author to be still running Windows 11 22H2 due to support ending on it. I don't believe you can even use the group policy to remain on a specific version past a specific version's support timeframe.

@Ramhound it is possible to just never install the update or willingly break Windows Update. But yes, it is very unlikely, which is exactly why I'm agreeing with you, but wanted to point out that there are always exceptions. :)

@LPChip and Ramhound (can't properly reference 2 users apparently) My comment forgot that it was a fresh install. Also I learned something new: I did not realize that "Reset My PC" has a cloud download option these days. It seems that feature is almost 5 years old now but hey! glad I learned something new. Thanks :)

Why would the new owner trust the drivers you've put on the pc? Surely anyone buying a second hand computer should reset it themselves?

@SamDean it depends on how skilled they are. Not everyone is techsavvy enough to do this nor want to invest time and money to let someone else do it. They tend to buy stuff from others, look at how the transaction was, and if it feels good enough, they'll just keep it like that. In any case, if I were to sell a PC, I would also try to give my customer the best experience. What they do afterwards is up to them, but at least, I feel good about the transaction myself.

@Ramhound I just reset my PC a couple weeks ago and it reinstalled 22H2, because that's what I had before.
On another note, I'd recommend after running the sysprep to test the result by booting back up and going through setup.  Once confirmed working as expected you can run sysprep again, just to make sure that works as intended.

Nope, Win11 22H2, and Windows Update says that it's fully up to date. Though this is a corporate environment, so they might be blocking some updates.
